# Deleted wav files from supporting files, but xcode still plays the files

Tags: ios

Im experiencing some issues related to playback of some wav files.
I added the wav files earlier by drag-and-dropping them into my Supporting files folder.
Now for some reason it will always play the sound of one particular file i tested earlier, and nothing else.

The wierd thing is that i deleted all the files and moved them to the trashbin - but still the same file will playback. It doesnt even exist! Any ideas how i can fix this? I tried Product > Clean already, and that didnt help. Here is a part of my code that I use to play the sound with:

```
//initiate sound
SystemSoundID completeSound = nil;

//yellow folder doesnt need folder
//blue folder (true folder) will need to use subdirectory:@"dirname"
NSURL *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:target_sound_filename withExtension:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)audioPath, &completeSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (completeSound);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One optimal solution is : Delete wav file from Trash also..Then try to delete app from simulator/device..Then close xcode completely.restart it.clean project and then check your wav file will not play.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the contents of the application folder worked! :) I used CMD+SHIFT+G in finder (/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator) and deleted the contents of the application folders. (I had version 6.0 and 6.1 folders, and each one had an Application folder). Files now seem to be properly removed, wierd bug though - I did not see any wav files in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Quit the Xcode and restart it. Also delete the application from device or simulator and re-deploy it.

Comment: Thank you! deleting the application from the simulator worked.